# The "This question already has answers here:" banner without target links. Is this a bug?

Tags: support, status-completed, duplicate-questions, banner

Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6392031/5779732).

Observe the duplicate banner at the top:

> [image: Banner]

As you can see, there is no target question specified in the banner. May be the target question is deleted or something else; that is not the question here.

Is this kind of UX a bug? Is this by design?