# What is recommended action for "This question already has answers where?" issue?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, banner

This is in continuation with my [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394317/5779732) question which is marked duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391505/5779732) question.

I learned that the "This question already has answers where?" issue is due to some mass-edit done by The Community user long back.

Following is the quote from an [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391506/5779732) by [Cody Gray♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray):

> If you come across additional anomalous questions, please raise a moderator flag or ping a gold badge holder in chat (if you're a regular anywhere where they hang out).

But, I think there was some degree of confusion/debate about this approach as they said following in comment:

> I firmly believe so, yes. However, Martijn's instincts apparently told him something different. That's bound to happen when you have humans as moderators; we're not all created equal. We are discussing it internally, and will let you know what the conclusion is. Sorry for the confusion that this created. – Cody Gray♦ Jan 21 at 19:43

I came across similar problem today with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4488969/5779732) question. I raised a moderator flag with following description:

> Please reopen the question and re-close with target mentioned in edit. I think this is problem created by Community user while mass-edit merging the banners in question body.

The flag got rejected:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Now, bad flag description may be the problem in *this particular* case. But, is that the only problem? Should users flag such questions in first place?

Taking each such question to meta will not be practical solution; lots of efforts.

I cannot take this to SOCVR because the question is old and without any new activity.

Without chat-rooms like SOCVR, it is difficult to find gold badge holder in *that particular* tag each time. Also, pinging them on some other question looks like spammy.

What is recommended action by normal users (below 10K, no gold badge) if they come across this issue?

Comment: If you know of someone that has a gold badge in a relevant tag, you can ask that user. Other than that, there's not much you can (or even should) do.

Comment: Personally, I would've provided a link to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391505/this-question-already-has-answers-where in my flag and stated that I was flagging as described in that post. That makes it clear *why* I'm using a custom mod flag instead of just using votes.

Comment: @Nick: I agree; I had that thought after flag rejected. The link would have been more helpful for moderator to understand why I flagged. Bad description may be the problem here. But, is that only problem? Should users flag such questions in first place?

Comment: What's also funny is that I, as a C# gold tag badge holder, don't see the "edit" link to edit the duplicates, but that the duplicate [appears to be registered and editable if you modify the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/originals/4488969/edit).

Comment: Well, the other mod and I discussed it. He said I made good points, but he didn’t say the magic words (“you’re right”), so I never updated the answer. Looks like I didn’t convince him. Or he forgot.