# This question already exists: ...?

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, closed-questions, post-notice

I think most of us already noticed the issue in the latest questions on meta where the duplicate banner is missing the duplicate target:

[The thin expanding blue line](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395985/8620333)

[Do our own accepted answers to our questions get counted for the Unsung Hero and Tenacious badges?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395982/8620333)

I think it happen only when the Community♦ is involved. Probably the same issue on the main site because I remember seeing this (not able to retrieve the examples to confirm if the Community♦ is also involved)

**UPDATE**

Another question where it's not happening: [Short Survey Banner Refuses to Go Away](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396000/8620333). There is another factor to activate the bug.

Comment: It's weird: instead of just failing to insert the target question, it's inserting a bunch of white space.

Comment: I've flagged the original question as per [this new MSE question for escalation of issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344586/369403), and hope it'll be addressed

Comment: I was just about to make this same report... Just to point out this is a different issue from [“This question already has answers here:” banner without target links. Is this a bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394317/7795130) because that bug is supposedly only present on old questions that didn't get converted to the new notice right. This issue seems to be present when a user *accepts* a duplicate flag/vote instead of it getting closed through the full vote process.

Comment: [Another question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396070/please-remove-this-incorrect-first-post-audit) succumbs to this mysterious plague

Comment: It also happens on main, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60952505/jsonobject-return-null-string

Comment: Instance of this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60982340/is-static-castintstdnumeric-limitsdoubleinfinity-defined-behaviour  . Maybe it is an April Fool joke. Duplicate but you can't even see the duplicate. Clicking "Edit" on where the duplicates are supposed to be, gives a 404 error

Comment: My question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61007723/why-is-this-powershell-variable-is-unused-according-to-vs-code has this problem, too. The link to the duplicate was posted as comment, and I voted close as first person, selecting "duplicate" with the link. When another person also voted duplicate, I got a banner asking "Does this answer your question?" When I clicked "Yes", i. e. accepting the duplicate vote, the question was closed and marked as duplicate without a link.

Comment: Another example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61033457/i-have-unwrap-problem-in-my-swift-core-data This seems to happen if the OP accepts the suggested duplicate.

Comment: Another example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61024681/692942

Comment: Yet another example where Community♦ is involved with the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61041846/2985643

Answer (score 4):

This issue is now fixed, as per [this meta.se post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345859/167668).

I have also verified that all links present here in this question and its comments are fixed as well.

I have noticed however that this issue could still happen for very old questions that were closed long before the system of post notices existed.

At the time, the Community user was simply adding a note by editing the post. Authors could then remove the note which was leaving the question in a similar state (as it was actually the case [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404942/525036) for instance).

In that case the post should be flagged for moderator attention as said by Cody Gray in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391506/525036). The mod will then reopen the question, and re-close it with the right duplicate based on the question history.