# Please remove this incorrect first-post audit

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

[This first post audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/25697976) tasks the reviewer to flag or downvote the only correct answer to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755735/how-to-extract-a-rar-archive-with-ruby/). Since the tag 'gem' is given, the currently accepted answer is incomplete (see also the asker's comment on that answer, stating he needs a gem-based answer).

The answer that here is given as 'low quality' is in fact the only correct answer: it posts the name of a gem-based solution, with the link as well. So I went back and reposted the answer, with a little bit of instructions taken from the link, at the risk of that becoming out-of-date with the project linked to.

However, that answer will keep coming up in the review-audit system, because one person downvoted it, and it was subsequently removed, hence it cannot be 'disputed' by another upvote. According to @BSMP; "What makes a post a candidate for being an audit is all votes on it being the same. It’s disagreement that stops it from being an audit." (he posted that on [my earlier identical question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394844/questionable-audit-question-only-correct-answer-was-deleted?noredirect=1#comment761198_394844), which someone helpfully tagged as duplicate and closed)

I am asking for a moderator to remove this particular answer from the first post audit system.

Comment: Someone flagged the post. And then it was deleted on review by four users. It's not only the single vote what decided it could be considered a "known bad" answer.

Comment: And "[no action needed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/25697976)" is particularly bad choice to review this post in "First Posts". It's a review queue that can help new users to understand what's expected on the site. By taking no action, you are telling them "this is fine". But [this is not fine](https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/2q97YCXcLOlkoR2jKKEMQ-wkG9k=/0x0:900x500/1200x800/filters:focal(378x178:522x322)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/49493993/this-is-fine.0.jpg).

Comment: This probably should be closed as a dupe of your earlier question.

Comment: when I receive an answer, I will gladly close my question

Comment: You've received an answer: other community users told you the audit was fine as it it. But it's fine, I'm not voting or close voting this question on any way. Good luck.

Comment: there was only one of those community users who actually looked at the content, rather than just broadly talking about link-only answers in general. The question as posed seeks only the name of a gem - I'm sure he knows how to integrate that once he has it. StackOverflow isn't supposed to be a popularity contest, but a platform where those who know the answers can post, and those who don't can stay out of the way.

Comment: Really? And how do you know who "actually looked at the content" and who didn't? Is there a way to track that that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Hans Passant dug through the project's issues on github and posted a link regarding rar support. I can't know for sure what the others looked at, but I can see that they do not comment on the library itself, which is the answer. Most of them only cast a downvote and moved on silently.

Comment: If you do not know, you shouldn't comment to that effect. I'm sure that at least another user "actually looked at the content", and I'm convinced others did as well. I'm out now. Good luck, although I believe you are wrong in pursuing this.

Comment: yes @gnat I think that question is more in line with what I was asking

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I should have posted a comment asking for further explanation on how to use the gem in the library. This would still have failed me the audit, but if it were a real post, that would be the Right Thing to do.

The issue is that 'no action needed' was selected for a post that needed action. That it was an answer or not is not at issue. The issue is that action was needed on the post. Selecting 'no action needed' on such a post prevents the OP from getting necessary feedback about the quality of the post.